If $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a ring morphism, and $M$ is a flat $A$-module, then $M_B := B \otimes_A M$ is a flat $B$-module.
The statement is: If $f:A\rightarrow B$ is a ring morphism, and $M$ is a flat $A$-module, then $M_B := B \otimes_A M$ is a flat $B$-module.
By a proposition in theory, proving that $M_B$ is a flat $B$-module is equivalent to showing the following:
$h:N\rightarrow N' \text{ injective} \Rightarrow h\otimes 1:N\otimes_B M_B \rightarrow N'\otimes_B M_B \text{ injective}$
where $h$ is any injective module homomorphism.
Now, without loss of generality (using canonical isomorphisms seen in theory), we have:
$ N\otimes_B M_B = N\otimes_B (B\otimes_A M)\cong (N\otimes_B B)\otimes_A M \cong (B\otimes_B N)\otimes_A M\cong N\otimes_A M $
Also, we have that the other tensor product $N'\otimes_B M_B\cong N'\otimes_A M$.
Therefore, since $h$ is injective and $M$ is a flat $A$-module by definition, and using the same proposition as before, we conclude that $h\otimes1:N\otimes_A M\rightarrow N'\otimes_A M$ is injective.
Does it make sense?

It may be simpler (but in essence the same) to use the following equivalent definition of flatness (in the exact category of modules over a fixed ring):
A module is flat if the functor "tensor product with it" is an exact functor.
In our case, this functor applied for $B$-modules in the component denoted by $\diamond$ is:
$$
\diamond\otimes_B(B\otimes_A M)
=
\diamond\otimes_A M\ ,
$$
and the last functor is exact, given that $M$ is flat. (A $B$-module is seen via the structural map $f$ as an $A$-module. Exactity for short exact sequences or chains over $B$ becomes an exactity over $A$.)

(The equality is above a natural transformation of functors on the $\diamond$ component.)

Your argument is valid without doubt.
But one might lose track of the maps after taking too many isomorphisms.
To polish your solution, investigate the commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
N\otimes_B(B\otimes_AM) @>{h\otimes\mathrm{id}_{M_B}}>> N'\otimes_B(B\otimes_AM)\\
@VV{\sim}V @VV{\sim}V \\
N\otimes_AM @>{h\otimes\mathrm{id}_M}>> N'\otimes_AM
\end{CD}$$
where all arrow are $B$-linear and so $A$-linear as well. On elements, the diagram is
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
n\otimes(b\otimes m) @>>> h(n)\otimes(b\otimes m)\\
@VVV @VVV \\
(bn)\otimes m @>>> (bh(n))\otimes m.
\end{CD}$$
Since $M$ is a flat $A$, the lower horizontal map is injective.
Using commutativity of the diagram, this makes the upper one injective as well.
